# How to beat Hex-Defense lvl 32 Border Patrol on hard?

Tags: hexdefense

I've almost finished the latest update for Hex Defense (which adds all levels upto 35). I beat all levels on Normal and all but one on hard, so I know the basics well. With beating I mean advancing in the levels waves far enough to get it to say 'next level' instead of 'retry level', this is somewhere around level 22.

**How can I beat level 32 on hard difficulty?**

Level 32 is call *Border Patrol* and has the creep walking on the sides of the screens, where you are not allowed to place any towers. The middles has a big field where you can place the towers. The normal strategy of starting with a laser tower doesn't work (because there are no places where you can align to hit several creeps with one shot). On easy I managed to eventually place on decently upgraded rocket tower in the middle (that can hit both sides). On hard I can't get past lvl4.

Comment: How did you beat it on normal?  I've made it to wave 20 once.  The purple creeps just wipe the floor with me.

Answer (score 1):

Wave 1: Place a gun 2 hexes down from top right. Rocket beneath that. When you get the money place gun below rocket. 3 creeps should escape.

Wave 2 and 3: After last creep travels 2-3 hexes, call in next wave .  Place gun 3-4 hexes up from bottom right,. The first creep that makes it to right side will escape (though some runs do turn out differently despite same towers, placement, etc.), but the 2nd should be picked off. While killing both waves, wait for money for another gun, place as far down on right side, but ahead of wave 3 creeps(some runs you can kill an extra creep on wave 2. Sell guns no longer shooting on left side and upgrade rocket when able. Should have 4-5 lives left, level 2 rocket on left and 2 guns on right.

Wave 4 and 5: Call 5 asap. Stack guns on right (play with it, some runs do better than others).

After that, I'm thinking sell guns and make new level 2 rocket (some runs need a first kill on wave 6 before upgrading rocket to level 2). Not sure about the rest. I usually hold out until wave 9, but somehow I managed 11, but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 0):

Better:

Wave one, place rocket half way down on left side. Half way through wave place second rocket on right side at the halfway point.

During second wave place a gun near the top right, literally as soon as you can afford it. This formation should keep you with full health for the next level, as well.

Upgrade the left rocket as soon as you can and the right one, as well. Once you've reached the third upgrade place a new rocket near the old. Do this until you have three on each side which are fully upgraded.

This had gotten me to stage 18. I still have yet to beat this stage....